# How to automatically refresh a IF formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Firstly let me say I am not a technical person or coder so am not very advanced with scripts/formula's etc and I need help with a possible automatic refresh if this is even possible?
I have a google sheet with multiple tabs and on one of the tabs I have this formula

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!$G11768="",F$1>=Sheet1!$E11768),F$1-Sheet1!$E11768,0)
```

This sits on row 11768 on sheet 'Avg age of tickets', and looks up another tab (Sheet1) row 11768 to do the calculation however if there is no data in that row it will return '43949' - what I want to do is have the formula automatically refresh somehow so when data is entered into row 11768 on Sheet1 that it then returns the correct value (usually 0). Is there any way to do this?

Currently, I am having to log in every day and pull down the formula from the cell above for it to re-calculate when ideally this should be touch-less as its used to produce charts for a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

go to your sheet: **`Avg age of tickets`** and delete the whole column where you have formulas you mentioned in your question. then paste this formula in the first row of that deleted column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Sheet1!$G1:G="")*(F$1>=Sheet1!$E1:E), F$1-Sheet1!$E1:E, 0))
```

if your data starts let's say from row 3 then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Sheet1!$G3:G="")*(F$1>=Sheet1!$E3:E), F$1-Sheet1!$E3:E, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I think I have worked out what the issue is which I still don't know how to fix. What is happening when data is being input into Sheet1, its being done as a line insert and therefor its changing =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Sheet1!$G3="")*(F$1>=Sheet1!$E3), F$1-Sheet1!$E3, 0)) to =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Sheet1!$G4="")*(F$1>=Sheet1!$E4), F$1-Sheet1!$E4, 0)) so the formula is always looking at the next blank line instead of staying looking at line 3. Is there a way to make it so the formula doesn't automatically change to the next line when a new line is inserted on Sheet1?

Comment: pls, share a copy/dummy of your sheet

Comment: I can't as it contains sensitive company information but just to give an overview. Two tabs Sheet1 and avg age of tickets. Sheet1 gets data populated into it  pulled from Trello using Zapier, the way the data as input into the sheet is a new line is inserted instead of the next blank line used. Then on tab avg age of tickets there is the formula you provided, which i have dragged down to the bottom of the page, however when a new line is inserted on sheet1 the formula changes from G3="" to G4=""0. I'm guessing it believes the original G3 field is now G4 as a line has been inserted above it.

Comment: well thats it... you are not supposed to drag it down. formula should stay in the first row... https://i.stack.imgur.com/UclAR.png

Comment: here I made you demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PHkRJ-xU6aA0v2gsmMio_UFBvXp1xVZPG03Ze6W5Di8/edit#gid=1356774295

Comment: Here I have made a copy of my sheet and removed the sensitive info https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YfTm4wgF64iKcRjUeKnGCHTJj6HcQd-gIkLKH2F5i3M/edit#gid=1092041450 but this gives you an idea of what I am doing. Data is created on Sheet1 as "insert line" by Zapier, but on Avg age of tickets i want the next line (11912) to automatically update when date is entered into line 11912 on 'Sheet1' instead of having to drag the formula down every time to refresh it

Comment: sheet you provided is private, pls share it